# Externals missing after Migration from Visual Source Safe

Tags: migration, visual-sourcesafe, visualsvn-server, svn-externals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how linked files in vss repository can be migrated to svn repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909218/how-linked-files-in-vss-repository-can-be-migrated-to-svn-repository)

I'm currently just finish migrating Visual SourceSafe Database into VisuallSVN using VSS2SVN Open Source Code. However i found out that the externals links is missing. It do migrate the link history, but do i need to manually configured the externals? it's such a huge database. Any migration tool or code can migrate and set external automatically?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909218/how-linked-files-in-vss-repository-can-be-migrated-to-svn-repository

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010, not eclipse, thus can't use Polarion SVN Importer. And like what Tim Long said, "it does carry over the shared items. In SVN, though, the items will no longer be shared. Each roject will have a separate copy". Hence i still need to set up external for each files and folder manually, is there got any importer tool can migrate and set external automatically? I really have no idea. Thanks for helping.